# How can I query a column of a dataframe on a specific value and get the values of two other columns corresponding to that value

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame where the first column contains various countries' ISO codes, while the other 2 columns contain dataset numbers and Linkedin profile links.

[Please refer to the image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yVFde.png)

I need to query the data frame's first "FBC" column on the "IND" value and get the corresponding values of the "no" and "Linkedin" columns.

Can somebody please suggest a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [query()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html):
If you want just the no and Linkedin values.

```
df = df.query("FBC.eq('IND')")[["no", "Linkedin"]]
```

If you want all 3:

```
df = df.query("FBC.eq('IND')")
```